Wilcoxon signed rank test vs Sign test assumptions
What assumptions must be checked for the Sign test?
If the Sign test is not valid either, what is the alternative?

The symmetry of differences is not an assumption on the W. test formulated generally. Rather, it is its H0 that that distribution is symmetric, and symmetric about 0. You can add the symmetry shape assumption thus making the W. test narrower in its meaning: H0 = "the mean difference is 0" (the nonparametric counterpart of the paired t-test).

@ttnphns, if you roll the symmetry into $H_0$, then when you reject $H_0$, you have no idea whether it is because the distribution was not symmetric, or was symmetric but not about $0$, or a bit of both.  To be able to accept an unambiguous alternative about the median/mean, the assumption is required. Now, if your alternative is about the pseudomedian, then no assumptionis required, nor do you need roll symmetry in the null.

You need symmetry under the null (it's not specifically a test for symmetry any more than the paired t test is,  but in order to get exchangeability of signs you require that symmetry under the null). Since the null is almost certainly false you don't require symmetry in the data. The main problem with your question is there's two pieces of information missing (the population parameter of interest and the kind of variable you're measuring)

For efficiency you symmetry under more than the null.  And the signed rank test may be considered obsolete in the face of the rank difference test.

It will, of course, depend on what you are trying to test/prove.
The Wilcoxon Signed Rank test (WSRt), in its most general form, is a test of the pseudomedian (aka Hodges–Lehmann estimator) of the differences. As such it has no distributional assumptions (assumption on the distribution of the parent population, its shape, etc.) The pseudo-median is a measure of "location", but it is not particularly intuitive, has no clear/systematic relationship to the mean or median, and will probably not be understood by your audience. If, and only if, the distribution of the differences is symmetric, then it becomes a test of the median, and of course of the mean as well. You say that your distribution of the differences is not symmetric, so .... So if you get a significant result, it could be because the pseudomedian location was not equal to 0 (or some other target), or because the distribution was not symmetric, or a little bit of both. The WSRt is not well behaved at all (as a test of the median) if the symmetry assumption is violated; indeed one can actually use the WSRt as a test of symmetry; test the sample against its observed median.
Note also that the WSRt computes the differences. But you say you used a Likert scale. The Likert scale is ordinal; to compute differences you need at least an interval scale. It is technically not valid to compute differences of Likert scale data (because $2-1$ may not be equal to $3-2$, $3-1$ may not be equal to $4-2$, etc.). I am pretty sure you labelled your categories $1,2,3,4,5$, but you might as well have labelled them $1,3,6,7,9$, or for that matter $A,B,C,D,E$. You can see that computing differences will be challenging. Note that this topic has been highly debated (see e.g. this paper for a decent historical perspective). Fwiw, my personal view is to treat Likert scores as strictly ordinal.
So, for these 2 reasons (assumption of symmetry, need for interval scale), use of the WSRt is not meaningful in your case.
The Sign test (St) is a test of the median. It has no distributional assumption as a test of the median. And it can legitimately be used with ordinal scale data (it does not compute differences, just compares values). If so, then why don't we use the St all the time? Obviously, there is no free lunch; you gain this convenience (no distributional assumption, ordinal scale) at the cost of power. St will have low power. It will be even more so if, as you describe, you have many ties; each tie, in some way, reinforces the null.
The 2 tests you mentioned are indeed the first which would come to mind. A few other ideas are possible.
One could use the Mann-Whitney U test (MWUt) (aka Wilcoxon Rank Sum test). Now, technically, it is used on 2 independent samples. But it is not clear whether one could also use it on paired samples (you certainly would lose the pairing information, which would reduce its power, but apart from this I can not see why it could not be used). Note that there is no consensus on using MWUt for paired data; I am not 100% sure it is a valid use, but I can not think of a potential problem (e.g. see this post on CV). Mann-Whitney U can be used with ordinal data (all it does is compare data points, not perform any arithmetic), is more powerful than the Sign test and tests for stochastic superiority (i.e. are the after scores significantly greater than the before scores?  $P(After>Before)>P(Before>After)$). Ties negatively affect its power as well.
Another option is to keep the pairing, and perform comparisons only between pairs (MWUt compares every Before sample to every After sample). For this, for each pair, compare the scores, and score it as Up/Down/Same (3 categories; score was Up, Down, or the Same). Say, e.g. you have 100 pairs; 20 went up, 10 went down, and 70 stayed the same. This gives you a 2x2 contingency table $\begin{matrix}20&10\\80&90\end{matrix}$, and you can use a Fisher-exact, or $\chi^2$ test (only if the values in the cells are large enough) (fwiw, in this example, the proportion of Up's is significantly greater than the proportion of Down's).

I advise against the MWUt. Dependence within subjects will invalidate the theory on which it is based, meaning that (a) it may not have the correct type I error probability, and (b) chances are that it is not "more powerful" than the Sign test as this statement would rely on independence.

@ChristianHennig, do you have a reference to some simulation which would show the problems with using MWUt on paired data?  (I am not sure how to "simulate" paired data??). This question (MWUt on paired data) has nagged me for a bit, and my searches have not found any probative answer (one way or the other).

The thing is that it will depend strongly on how the dependence plays out, and there are many possibilities. Chances are that depending on whether dependence is positive or negative, either type I or type II error probability will be bad but not both. I'm not aware of literature, it's my intuition. But honestly, ignoring dependence  in paired data looks obviously wrong to most statisticians, so chances are they wouldn't even find it worthwhile to simulate it.

The easiest way to simulate paired data is to simulate from a bivariate normal where you can tune dependence by correlation. This isn't exactly the situation of this question, but I wouldn't expect things to be much different for Likert data that may be modelled stemming from a latent normal. In any case it should be obvious that the theory behind MWUt is invalidated by this.

@ChristianHennig, thanks for the pointers
